# Can people see if they are affected by negative aura from invisible enemies?

Tags: dota-2

For example, if a bounty hunter carrying an assault cuirass turns invisible and roams near an enemy hero, will the enemy hero see the assault cuirass debuff in their buff section (just above the HP bar), thus indicating the presence of an invisible hero?

Comment: This is why Radiance can be turned off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they can. You can also see positive buffs on your enemies if they have an allied invis hero (with let's say a Vladimir's offering) near them.

Comment: This is how it works atm but it is a bug (except for radiance)! http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=13563 search for "['12.03.09] Auras work with invisible units"

Comment: @Wandang In dota 1 you could see creep with vlad auras if a riki with vlad was invis near by so I'm not 100% its a bug. I've seen on one of your post that you wrote several script for dota. Would you mind putting them somewhere downloadable ? That would be great Thanks. Regards - WizLiz

Comment: Wrong. I just tested it with v6.79c. I never experienced otherwise in my dotayears. (tested it again with 79c after i tested with 6.77 testmode)

Comment: @Wandang Well that might have changerd because I remember times where getting vlad on riki was bad because everybody could see you come due to the aura on allied creeps (When I was a new player). Well anyway thanks for the information, I'll update my answer if it get patched in game

Comment: i dont like putting up all scripts somewhere without some infos. i am going to ask questions how to archive something in dota and answer it myself on this platform instead. if you want something specific you can ask it on this platform too and i will try to build it for you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is possible to see negative and positive (on enemy) buffs while the carrier of the items is invisible but it is not meant to be.

It is a known bug on the [Known Bugs List](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=13563) search for "Auras work with invisible units."

Comment: Does any one remember if in Dota 1 it was like this as well?

Comment: @TonySniper no, otherwise it would not be on the buglist ;)